# Is there an easier way to set autohotkey Gui Listbox's to default to what was last chosen?

Tags: user-interface, optimization, autohotkey

I wanted to find out if there is an easier way to have a GUI listbox default to its last chosen option besides just manually making if statements for each option like I have done.
Currently it is rather hard to scale this to more scripts and more choices, so even though what I have works I would like a simpler way to accomplish the same thing.
For reference this script simply opens a gui that allows me to pick another script to run in the appropriate folder.

```
#NoEnv  ; Recommended for performance and compatibility with future AutoHotkey releases.; 
#Warn  ; Enable warnings to assist with detecting common errors.
SendMode Input  ; Recommended for new scripts due to its superior speed and reliability.
SetWorkingDir %A_ScriptDir%  ; Ensures a consistent starting directory.
MasterLoc = %A_ScriptDir%
SArray := StrSplit(MasterLoc, "\")
ExcludeMaster := SArray[Sarray.Count()]
MasterLoc := RegExReplace(MasterLoc, ExcludeMaster)
DATADIR = %MasterLoc%Data\
IniRead, LastMultiChoice, %DATADIR%Variables.ini, LastMultiChoice, Choice
Gui, Add, Text,, Select A Script to Run
If LastMultiChoice=Error
    Gui, Add, ListBox, vChoice w130 h125, Run Folders|Run Print|Quote and Plot|Read HTM2|Run Plots wExport|Production Run wExport|New Design|Run Folders wEx|
Else if LastMultiChoice=Run Folders
    Gui, Add, ListBox, vChoice w130 h125, Run Folders||Run Print|Quote and Plot|Read HTM2|Run Plots wExport|Production Run wExport|New Design|Run Folders wEx|
Else if LastMultiChoice=Run Print
    Gui, Add, ListBox, vChoice w130 h125, Run Folders|Run Print||Quote and Plot|Read HTM2|Run Plots wExport|Production Run wExport|New Design|Run Folders wEx|
Else if LastMultiChoice=Quote and Plot
    Gui, Add, ListBox, vChoice w130 h125, Run Folders|Run Print|Quote and Plot||Read HTM2|Run Plots wExport|Production Run wExport|New Design|Run Folders wEx|
Else if LastMultiChoice=Read HTM2
    Gui, Add, ListBox, vChoice w130 h125, Run Folders|Run Print|Quote and Plot|Read HTM2||Run Plots wExport|Production Run wExport|New Design|Run Folders wEx|
Else if LastMultiChoice=Run Plots wExport
    Gui, Add, ListBox, vChoice w130 h125, Run Folders|Run Print|Quote and Plot|Read HTM2|Run Plots wExport||Production Run wExport|New Design|Run Folders wEx|
Else if LastMultiChoice=Production Run wExport
    Gui, Add, ListBox, vChoice w130 h125, Run Folders|Run Print|Quote and Plot|Read HTM2|Run Plots wExport|Production Run wExport||New Design|Run Folders wEx|  
Else if LastMultiChoice=New Design
    Gui, Add, ListBox, vChoice w130 h125, Run Folders|Run Print|Quote and Plot|Read HTM2|Run Plots wExport|Production Run wExport|New Design||Run Folders wEx|  
Else if LastMultiChoice=Run Folders wEx
    Gui, Add, ListBox, vChoice w130 h125, Run Folders|Run Print|Quote and Plot|Read HTM2|Run Plots wExport|Production Run wExport|New Design||Run Folders wEx||
Else
    MsgBox, Error. %LastMultiChoice% is unrecognized.
Gui, Add, Button, default, Done
Gui, Show,, Choice
WinSet, AlwaysOnTop, On, Choice
return

ButtonDone:
Gui, Submit
Check1 := StrSplit(Choice, " ").1
If Check1=Run
    Run, %MasterLoc%PLOT Scripts\%Choice%.ahk
Else if Check1=Production
    Run, %MasterLoc%Production Scripts\%Choice%.ahk
Else
    Run, %MasterLoc%Extra Scripts\%Choice%.ahk
IniWrite, %Choice%, %DATADIR%Variables.ini, LastMultiChoice, Choice
ExitApp

GuiClose:
ExitApp

~^SPACE::ExitApp
```

Comment: Can you use a `GuiControl ChooseString, YOUR_LISTBOX_ID,  %LastMultiChoice%` after you show the GUI?

Comment: That does exactly what I wanted thanks!

Comment: I'll go make it a full answer for people seeing this in the future.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of defining a new default based on the previous choice, use the same ListBox each time, and then use `GuiControl ChooseString` to pick the previous choice after it loads.